# What does makefile dependencies mean?

Tags: makefile

I'm involved in a project that is organized into different modules. In each one there are binaries and headers (*.c , *.h ), and a Makefile. At the top level there's one Makefile that compiles all.
I'm looking under a module and I find this expression in the local Makefile:

```
ifdef CONFIG_MCENTER
  MODULE_DEPS += mcenter
endif
```

Does this mean that this module includes all mcenter binaries and functions ?

Comment: As far as (GNU) `make` is concerned, all it means is that the string "mcenter" is added to the value of make variable `MODULE_DEPS`.  The significance of doing so depends entirely on how that variable is used in that makefile.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/search?q=makefile+dependencies